# How to typecast Sequence of primitive types to NewTypes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, typing

Say I have a function that returns a list of `str`s. I want to assign it to a list of NewTypes that inherit from `str`.

Unfortunately, I can't find a way to do this with the `typing` module. The only solution I have is looping through the list, convert every single element and append it to a new list. How is this normally handled?

Thank you.

```py
import pathlib 
from typing import List, NewType

Line = NewType('Line', str)
Lines = NewType('Lines', List[Line])

def read(
    file_name: str,
) -> List[str]:
    file_path = pathlib.Path.cwd() / file_name
    ret = file_path.read_text().splitlines(keepends=True)
    return ret

def main():
    a: Lines
    a = Lines(
        read("a.txt") # type problem: str is incompatible with Line
    )
```

Comment: you could just use `typing.cast`...

Comment: Ah nice, can't believe I haven't encountered this before! haha